# Derivative of a tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I have a rank-2 tensor given by

$$
P_{\alpha \beta} = p\delta_{\alpha \beta} + (u_1^2, u_1u_2 ; u_1u_2, u_2^2)
$$

whose derivative with respect to $x_{\alpha}$ I would like to find. According to my lecture notes this is given by

$$
\partial_{x_\alpha} P_{\alpha \beta} = \rho u_\alpha \partial_{x_\alpha}u_\beta + \partial_{x_\alpha}p
$$

I have no idea why this equality is valid. How does one take a derivate of a tensor?

Comment: @Franck, please don't go on these editing sprees that fill up the front page with old questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Not my fault if retagging push questions to the front page...

Comment: Retagging pushes questions to the front page. If you didn't know this before, you know it now. Please: no editing sprees. Edit 3 or 4 questions a day, not 30 in an hour. Please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK. I'm trying to stay away from the metas, but probably worth pinging them again, e.g. the 4-year-old feature request: [It should be possible to retag a question without bumping it to the front page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29394/178179).

Comment: Where did $\rho$ come from?